# Changing Image in User Control with DataTrigger

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to change an image in a user control when a DependancyProperty on that user control is changed. As an example, I have the DependancyProperty StatusIndicator as a boolean. When it is true, I want to show the StatusOK image, and when its false I want to show the StatusBad image.

The data trigger seems to set the style of the image fine when the application first loads, since the StatusIndicator is false it sets the source of the image to StatusBad from StatusDisabled.

The problem is when I change the StatusIndicator value, the DataTriggers don't seem to notice. I monitored the change using WpfInspector, and it would always think that the StatusIndicator is false.

Below is the XAML.

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication6.StatusControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="335" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="ThisUserControl">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="StatusDisabled" UriSource="/WpfApplication6;component/Images/status_light_gray.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="StatusBad" UriSource="/WpfApplication6;component/Images/status_red.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="StatusOK" UriSource="/WpfApplication6;component/Images/status_light_green.png" />
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}" x:Key="StatusImage">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource StatusDisabled}" />
            <Setter Property="RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode" Value="HighQuality" />

            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger                     
                    Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=StatusIndicator}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource StatusBad}" />
                </DataTrigger>

                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ThisUserControl, Path=StatusIndicator}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource StatusOK}" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Image Style="{StaticResource StatusImage}" Grid.Row="0" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

And the code-behind.

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication6
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for StatusControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class StatusControl : UserControl
    {
        public StatusControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusIndicatorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "StatusIndicator", typeof(bool), typeof(bool), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        public bool StatusIndicator
        {
            get { return (bool)this.GetValue(StatusIndicatorProperty); }
            set { this.SetValue(StatusIndicatorProperty, value); }
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second type should be your owner Type `StatusControl`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusIndicatorProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "StatusIndicator", typeof(bool), typeof(StatusControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Agh! I've spent so much time on this oversight. That fixed it. Thank you so much! (I will mark this as answered as soon as the site will allow me)